# Use of 'this' in a JavaScript object using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Lately I've been trying to make an object in JavaScript with the following structure:

```
function colorDiv(div){
      this.div=div;
      this.div.bind("click",this.changeColor)
      this.changeColor(){
            this.div.css("background", "#FF0000");
      }
}
```

The problem is that the `changeColor` method cannot be called from the jQuery environment because `this` must refer to the current `colorDiv` object, so the bind method cannot work as expected.
How can this be solved?

Comment: I believe the issue is that if you are going to use jquery methods like bind or css, you need to do it within the context of jquery, i.e. $(div).bind, $(div).css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple ways. The simplest is as follows:

```
function ColorDiv(div) {
      var that = this;

      that.div = div;
      that.div.bind("click", that.changeColor);

      that.changeColor = function () {
            that.div.css("background", "#FF0000");
      };
}

var colorDiv = new ColorDiv($("#my-div"));
$("#something-else").click(colorDiv.changeColor);
```

You save a reference to `this` in the variable `that`, which is just the name commonly used in the JavaScript world for exactly this purpose. Then you refer to `that` instead of `this` inside your `changeColor` method. (Note that I used `that` everywhere, just for consistency, even though the only place it actually makes a difference is inside the `changeColor` method.)

---

Another is to use the [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method. You can either use it every time you call `changeColor`, like so:

```
var colorDiv = new ColorDiv($("#my-div"));
$("#something-else").click(colorDiv.changeColor.bind(colorDiv));
```

or you can use it in the `ColorDiv` class to ensure that all methods are bound correctly whenever they are called:

```
this.changeColor = (function () {
    this.div.css("background", "#FF0000");
}).bind(this);
```

As noted in the linked article, `Function#bind` is not supported in all browsers, so you'll need a shim like the one they give, or possibly a [full-fledged ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim).

Underscore.js has a [bindAll](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll) function that could be useful here, too, especially with multiple methods:

```
_.bindAll(this);
```

---

Finally, it's worth noting you don't really need to do any of this in your particular example: just do

```
this.changeColor = function () {
    div.css("background", "#FF0000");
};
```

instead of what you have, i.e. reference the `div` variable passed in, instead of the reference stored in `this.div`, since they are the same thing.

Comment: Thanks dude, I was looking for something like the bind function. Sad that it doesn't work in 'not so new' browsers, but i'll give underscore a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting as the first line of the method:

```
var self = this;
```

and then using self as needed.

```
this.div.bind("click",self.changeColor)
```

Comment: Careful: Although `self` is not a reserved word, it's a predefined variable that references the `window` object. See [window.self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.self)